# Indexed delete in django

Tags: python, mysql

I am doing the following in django to delete all duplicate names except for the first one:

```
for item in CreditPerson.objects.filter(name=person.name).order_by('id')[1:]: 
    item.delete()
```

Is there a way to do this entirely in a django query? If so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CreditPerson.objects.filter(pk__in=CreditPerson.objects.filter(name=person.name).values_list('pk', flat=True)[1:]).delete()
```

Comment: No. `AssertionError: Cannot use 'limit' or 'offset' with delete.`